# Record Mouse and Keyboard Movements into TXT file - Python

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am interested to see if there is a way to store mouse and keyboard movements to automate some repetitive tasks.

Right now, I am able to send mouse and keyboard movements using pyautogui like this:

```
pyautogui.moveTo(X, Y) # Move the mouse to XY coordinates.
pyautogui.write('Chrome', interval=0.25) # Write 'Chrome'
pyautogui.press('enter')  # Press the Enter key
```

I know the old saying goes

> The computer will always do exactly what you TELL it to do.

However, in this case, I would like to SHOW the computer how do it, and have those actions be recorded into like a text file or something that can be called at some point in the script. If that makes sense.

Would it make more sense / be more practical to just call out each stroke/click like above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want a log of actions in a txt file to be then read and reproduced by `pyautogui`.

There are many libraries for that like `pynput` that offer simple listeners to actions like mouse clicks, keyboard inputs... like so:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="mouse_log.txt", level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_move(x, y):
    logging.info("Mouse moved to ({0}, {1})".format(x, y))

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        logging.info('Mouse clicked at ({0}, {1}) with {2}'.format(x, y, button))

def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    logging.info('Mouse scrolled at ({0}, {1})({2}, {3})'.format(x, y, dx, dy))

with Listener(on_move=on_move, on_click=on_click, on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

You will then have a `mouse_log.txt` file to be parsed and to execute `pyautogui` actions accordingly. That introduces a further level of indirection and could be more error prone, so I'd go with the plain `pyautogui` script you have mentioned.